# Why is my random command not playing a random file?

Tags: raspbian, python, video

I am trying to play a random video file upon an input from a PIR sensor.

Rasberry Pi 3, running Rasbian.

Problem is, I don't know what I'm doing and just trying to hack together different files.

So far, I have the PIR detection script (pirDetect) working, and the playback file also works, except instead of playing back a random file in the directory, it plays back the same one over and over on every detection.

Here is what I am using at the moment:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess as sp
import time
from pirDetect import *
import random
import os

directory = "."

video = ["omxplayer", "filename", "-o", "local"]
scareFile = random.choice(os.listdir(directory))

def onMotion(currState):
    if currState:
            video[1] = scareFile
            subVideo = sp.Popen(video)
            while subVideo.poll() is None:
                    time.sleep(.1)

objDetect = detector(7)
objDetect.subscribe(onMotion)
objDetect.start()
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your code the value of `scarefile` is just initialized once. since you need a different file to be selected every time motion is detected a you need to pick a new file from within the `onMotion` function like so

```
def onMotion(currState):
  if currState:
    scareFile = random.choice(os.listdir(directory))
    video[1] = scareFile
    subVideo = sp.Popen(video)
    while subVideo.poll() is None:
      time.sleep(.1)
```

Comment: That is working like a charm. Thank you.  I wish I knew how to troubleshoot like that.

Answer (score 0):

the random file is selected once in the beginning of the script, then it doesn't get changed anymore. you need to call the `choice` function each time the omxplayer is called.

Comment: That makes sense.  When I run the script after stopping it, it will play a different file over and over. I'll give that a try.